# What is a good way to load many pictures and their reference in an array? - Java + ImageJ

Tags: java, arrays, image, load, imagej

I have for example 1000 images and their names are all very similar, they just differ in the number. "ImageNmbr0001", "ImageNmbr0002", ....., ImageNmbr1000 etc.;
I would like to get every image and store them into an ImageProcessor Array.

So, for example, if I use a method on element of this array, then this method is applied on the picture, for example count the black pixel in it. 
I can use a for loop the get numbers from 1 to 1000, turn them into a string and create substrings of the filenames to load and then attach the string numbers again to the file name and let it load that image.
However I would still have to turn it somehow into an element I can store in an array and I don't a method yet, that receives a string, in fact the file path and returns the respective ImageProcessor that is stored at it's end.

Also my approach at the moment seems rather clumsy and not too elegant. So I would be very happy, if someone could show me a better to do that using methods from those packages:

```
import ij.ImagePlus;
import ij.plugin.filter.PlugInFilter;
import ij.process.ImageProcessor;
```

I think I found a solution:

```
Opener opener = new Opener();  
String imageFilePath = "somePath";
ImagePlus imp = opener.openImage(imageFilePath);
ImageProcesser ip = imp.getProcessor();
```

That do the job, but thank you for your time/effort.

Comment: Show us your approach.

Comment: As I said I don't know how to fill an ImageProcessor Array with images. 
Also: The method I had described could also be used to create a String Array that contains all the names of the said pictures I want to store. I haven't coded this so far, but I don't see any problem, apart from that the length of that part of the code feels too long and that there is surely a better and nice solution, if one knows the right method to do that for one, maybe with some minor changes/fixe so it works smoothly.

Comment: If you can help it, don't load the image until you need it

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I undestand what you want exacly... But I definitly would not save each information of each image in separate files for 2 reasons:
- It's slower to save and read the content of multiple files compare with 1 medium size file
- Each file adds overhead (files need Path, minimum size in disk, etc)

If you want performance, group multiple image descriptions in single description files.

If you dont want to make a binary description file, you can always use a Database, which is build for it, performance in read and normally on save.

I dont know exacly what your needs, but I guess you can try make a binary file with fixed size data and read it later

**Example:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    FileOutputStream fout = null;
    FileInputStream fin = null;

    try {
        fout = new FileOutputStream("description.bin");
        DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(fout);

        for (int x = 0; x < 1000; x++) {
            dout.writeInt(10); // Write Int data
        }

        fin = new FileInputStream("description.bin");
        DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(fin);
        for (int x = 0; x < 1000; x++) {
            System.out.println(din.readInt()); // Read Int data
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

    } finally {
        if (fout != null) {
            fout.close();
        }
        if (fin != null) {
            fin.close();
        }
    }
}
```

In this example, the code writes integers in "description.bin" file and then read them.
This is pretty fast in Java, since Java uses "channels" for files by default